# How to delete ~ without deleting my home directory?

Tags: linux, bash

By mistake while using `vim` when exiting using `:wq!` I type an extra character (`~`) this created a directory named `~`; however if I `cd` into it it would take me to the current user's `home`. How can I remove this directory without **actually** remove my home directory?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but the short answer is `rmdir './~'` typed _exactly as shown_.

Comment: Quitting Vim is taken to a whole new level. I'm afraid the next post will be "I crashed the plane by mistake while trying to quit Vim".

Comment: Look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/519681/bash-created-a-tilde-in-a-directory-by-accident)

Answer (score 4):

Just quote the `~`. Use `rmdir`, **not** `rm`, to be safe (`rmdir` will only remove an empty directory, so won't get rid of your home directory even if you mess it up).

```
$ mkdir '~'
$ ls -la '~'
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 me users  4096 Apr 20 13:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 97 me users 12288 Apr 20 13:20 ..
$ rmdir '~'
$ ls -la '~'
ls: cannot access ~: No such file or directory
$
```

Comment: If that is the case, then the safest thing is to change into that directory and then `rm` files there, rather than risking an `rm` command with ~ in it. Somthing like `cd '~'` followed by `ls -la` should show you any files in that directory, which you can then individually `rm`.

Answer (score 3):

It can be solved using `rm -rfi ./\~`, which explicitly specifies the current directory.

(*) Similar question already ask [here](https://superuser.com/questions/519681/bash-created-a-tilde-in-a-directory-by-accident) (thanks @AvihooMamka)

Comment: We tag users using @username (not linking to their profile).

Comment: @MarounMaroun how can you do that from an answer on which `@user` did not participate in?

Comment: This is fine, but be _very_ careful using any `rm` command with both `-rf` and `~` as parameters, just in case... :-)

Answer (score 1):

All of the recommended ways didn't help in my case. So I did:

```
rm -rf ./'~'
```

and it helped to get rid of "~" directory in my user dir.